# Getting HDFS Location of Hive Table in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am trying to parse out the Location from Hive partitioned table in Spark using this query:

```
val dsc_table = spark.sql("DESCRIBE FORMATTED data_db.part_table")
```

I was not able to find any query or any other way in Spark to specifically select Location column from this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

df.inputFiles method in dataframe API will print file path. 
It returns a best-effort snapshot of the files that compose this DataFrame.

```
spark.read.table("DB.TableName").inputFiles
Array[String]: = Array(hdfs://test/warehouse/tablename)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use **`.toDF`** method on `desc formatted table` then filter from dataframe.

***`DataframeAPI:`***

```
scala> :paste
spark.sql("desc formatted data_db.part_table")
.toDF //convert to dataframe will have 3 columns col_name,data_type,comment
.filter('col_name === "Location") //filter on colname
.collect()(0)(1)
.toString
```

***`Result:`***

```
String = hdfs://nn:8020/location/part_table
```

**`(or)`**

***`RDD Api:`***

```
scala> :paste
spark.sql("desc formatted data_db.part_table")
.collect()
.filter(r => r(0).equals("Location")) //filter on r(0) value
.map(r => r(1)) //get only the location
.mkString //convert as string
.split("8020")(1) //change the split based on your namenode port..etc
```

***`Result:`***

```
String = /location/part_table
```

Comment: This answer gives the right result, usually we only want to know the folder name.
All other answers provided here, provides individual file names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use spark's utility of table reading:

`spark.read.table("myDB.myTable").select(input_file_name).take(1)`
Will result in a string like:

```
19/06/18 09:59:55 WARN util.Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
res1: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([hdfs://nameservice1/my/path/to/table/store/part-00000-d439163c-9fc4-4768-8b0b-c963f5f7d3d2.snappy.parquet])
```

I used `take(1)` only to print one row to show the result here. You may not want to use it if you want all the locations.
From this result you can parse the string accordingly in case you want only the location part.

Comment: Is this specific for spark 2.4 version?

Comment: No. I did it in `2.1`.  But this should work in `2.4` as well. I haven't seen any relevant update of deprecating any of the used methods.

Comment: what is `input_file_name` ?

Comment: @GaurangShah it's a function exposing the name of the input file, similar to hive's virtual INPUT__FILE__NAME column. find it here in spark's source code: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/inputFileBlock.scala#L30

Answer (score 2):

Didnt find an answer in Pyspark

```
table_location = spark.sql("describe formatted DB.TableName").filter((F.col('col_name')=='Location')).select("data_type").toPandas().astype(str)['data_type'].values[0]
```